# How to create a purchase order with multiple line items in quickbook v3 PHP api

Tags: php, api, quickbooks

I am using Quickbooks V3 by following this package. https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

I am able to create invoice with multiple line items like here https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/example_invoice_add.php

I want to create purchase order with multiple line items like invoice, how to do it?

Comment: Can you please show us what you've tried?

Comment: This is the PHP Code http://pastebin.com/XMMbSziu 
This is my XML data of that request.. http://pastebin.com/cZd9j1QL
This is my XML Response http://pastebin.com/VBg24Yiy @Andy

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to create invoice with multiple line items like here

OK.

> I want to create purchase order with multiple line items like invoice, how to do it?

The exact same way.

```
$PO = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_PurchaseOrder();
$PO->setVendorRef($ref);
$PO->setDocNumber('1234');
$PO->setTxnDate('2016-07-27');

$Line = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line();
$Line->setDetailType('SalesItemLineDetail');
$Line->setAmount(20.0000 * 1.0000 * 0.516129);
$Line->setDescription('Test description goes here.');
$SalesItemLineDetail = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_SalesItemLineDetail();
$SalesItemLineDetail->setItemRef('8');
$SalesItemLineDetail->setUnitPrice(20 * 0.516129);
$SalesItemLineDetail->setQty(1.00000);
$Line->addSalesItemLineDetail($SalesItemLineDetail);

$PO->addLine($Line);

$PurchaseOrderService->add($Context, $realm, $PO);
```

If you're having trouble, please post the XML request sent to QuickBooks, and the XML response you got back, and your code.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.
This is the response i am getting from above code..

**2020: [Required param missing, need to supply the required value for the API, Required parameter Line
.DetailType is missing in the request]**

Comment: Did you read my answer?  I said: "If you're having trouble, please post the XML request sent to QuickBooks, and the XML response you got back, and your code."    Please do that.

Comment: Sorry, this is my XML data of that request..
http://pastebin.com/cZd9j1QL

Comment: Where is the XML response you got back? Where is your code?